# Why doesn't method = "update" work when using "transforms" to filter in R plotly

Tags: r, data-visualization, r-plotly

I'm fairly new to r plotly so I'm still getting accustomed to all the arguments. One topic that I'm exploring is how to create a dropdown menu event by filtering. I found this helpful example using the iris dataset found here https://community.plotly.com/t/need-help-on-using-dropdown-to-filter/6596/2, it's the same code I provided below with some slight changes. I was experimenting with how I can change the annotations and shapes for the  "Setosa" and "Versicolor" histograms respectively while still being able to change the graphic in terms of the data. However, when I tried to use method = "update" in layout(), the annotations/shapes changed, but the data remained the same even when I toggled between "Setosa" and "Versicolor." Does anybody know why this happens, and how to fix it?

Here is the reproducible code. I want to be able to filter the histogram graphics that correspond to the flower species (to create a dropdown menu) while changing their annotations/shapes simultaneously.

```
library(plotly)
datasets::iris



line_shape <- list(type = "line",
                         x0 = 0,
                         x1 = 1,
                         xref = "paper",
                         y0 = 6,
                         y1 = 6,
                         line = list(color = "black"))

line_shape2 <- list(type = "line",
                   x0 = 0,
                   x1 = 1,
                   xref = "paper",
                   y0 = 6,
                   y1 = 6,
                   line = list(color = "red"))





line_annotation <- list( x = 5, y = 6.4, xref = "x", yref = "y",
                        text = "Sepal", showarrow = FALSE,
                        font = list(color = 'black'))


line_annotation2 <- list( x = 5, y = 6.4, xref = "x", yref = "y",
                         text = "Sepal", showarrow = FALSE,
                         font = list(color = 'red'))


p <- iris %>%
  plot_ly(
    type = 'histogram', 
    x = ~Sepal.Length,
    transforms = list(
      list(
        type = 'filter',
        target = ~Species,
        operation = '=',
        value = unique(iris$Species)[1]
      )
    )) %>% layout(
      updatemenus = list(
        list(
          type = 'dropdown',
          active = 0,
          buttons = list(
            list(method = "update",
                 args = list(list("transforms[0].value", unique(iris$Species)[1]),
                             list(shapes = list(line_shape, c()),
                              annotations = list(line_annotation, c()))),
                 label = unique(iris$Species)[1]),
            list(method = "update",
                 args = list(list("transforms[0].value", unique(iris$Species)[2]),
                        list(shapes = list(c(), line_shape2),
                        annotations = list(c(), line_annotation2))),
                 label = unique(iris$Species)[2])
          )
        )
      )
    )
p
```